# use of decision variables in constraint assignments - PuLP

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, constraints, pulp

I am working on a specific problem utilizing linear programming and am trying to familiarize myself with PuLP. My issue is that several of my constraints contain only some of the decision variables and I am trying to find an efficient way to select them.

Here's what I mean:

I setup a list for all my Decision Variables.

```
investments = ["1_t1", "2_t1", "1_t2", "2_t2", "1_t3", "2_t3"]
```

Then I put those variables in a dictionary.

```
invmt_vars = LpVariable.dicts("Invmts",investments,lowBound=0,cat='Continuous')
```

Then I setup the Objective Function, simply as the sum of those variables.

```
prob += lpSum(invmt_vars[i] for i in invmt_vars), 'Sum of all investments'
```

Then I have Constraints like this example:

```
prob += 1_t1 + 2_t2 + 3_t2 <= 25
```

This works for a smaller number of variables, but I'd eventually like to add hundreds of variables. Is there a way to loop through the variables dictionary so that I only get the variables I'm looking for, without having to type them all out?

So far, I have really only seen constraint assignments that involve looping through the whole dictionary, like this:

```
prob += lpSum([ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) == 100, "PercentagesSum"
```

It would be great, for example, if I could simply leave Decision Variables in a list and use `range` loop.

I appreciate any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulp leverages the power of list comprehensions to do this look at the documentation in, http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk

Comment: figured it through. thanks for pointing me in the right direction.